# In search of motivation (Examples from nature) for reaction-diffusion systems with a conservation law

Tags: ecology, theoretical-biology, literature

I'm an applied mathematician with a huge interest in mathematical biology. While looking at  this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2401.12660), I came across with the following:

> Examples of reaction-diffusion systems (1)-(2), falling into the class
> of systems we are interested in, are for instance the Brusselator, the
> Schnakenberg, the Gray-Scott and the Gierer-Meinhardt model coupled to
> a conservation law coming for instance from ecology.

Although I googled a lot, I couldn't find any example/reference from ecology which satisfies the above. Since at the end of the day, I am simply a mathematician, I thought to ask the experts of that forum. Having a motivation can help someone gain easier intuition on the expected results, which is really important.

**Question:** What are some examples of reaction-diffusion systems, coupled to a conservation law, coming from biology? I'm looking for a rather simple reference or examples from daily life (if any).

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please try to use a descriptive title that makes it easy for interested people to recognize they'd be interested in your question.

Comment: [Paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0307904X14000791), [Chapter](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/0470871296)

Comment: @BryanKrause You're absolutely right. I edited my title, hope that it's better now

Comment: @RoniSaiba thank you very much, I'll check that!

Comment: There is [a whole book here](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=Cl8e4-4oWBwC&oi=fnd&pg=PR7&dq=ecology+conservation+law+reaction-diffusion&ots=KXeSiO4Qg_&sig=nOP4z-_zYEgeXffQtnbNu1KiVgI#v=onepage&q&f=false) from spatial ecology. there appear to also be some [applications in biochemistry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fick%27s_laws_of_diffusion) involving adsorption or consumption across a spatial gradient.